# run celery task using a django management command

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I'm trying to run a task, using celery 3.1, from a custom management command.

If I call my task from a view it works fine but when starting the same task from my management command, the task will only run synchronous in current context (not async via celery).

I don't have djcelery installed.

What do I need to add to my management command to get async task processing on command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing Celery tasks from a command line utility is the same as executing them from views. If you have a task called `foo`, then **in both cases**:

- Calling `foo(...)` executes the code of the task as if `foo` were just a plain Python function.
- Calling `foo.delay(...)` executes the code of the task asynchronously, through a Celery worker.